# Что нужно выучить чтобы писать 3d игры (стрелялки)?

Tags: разработка-игр, книги, 3d

Преимущественно на С++

Если бы я задал вопрос, "что нужно выучить чтобы создавать веб сайты" я бы хотел увидеть следующий ответ

- html
- css
- javascript (jquery)
- php (perl)
- mysql (postgresql)
- Apache, nginx (сервера)

Так же стоит изучить (что стоит посмотреть в гугле)

- memcache, apc (кэширование на строне сервера)
- nodejs
- html5, css3
- Ajax (это относится к javascript)
- отправка файла через iframe (это относится к javascript)
- webgl
- pdo, mysqlli (это относится к php, подключение к бд)
- denver, xampp (локальный веб сервер для тестирования сайтов)
- InnoDB, MyISAM (это относится к MySQL)
- Sphinx (поисковый движок)
- .htaccess и mod_rewrite

Готовые движки

- livestreet
- wordpress
- drupal
- joomla
- simpla
- opencart

Вот примерно такой ответ хочу увидеть на свой вопрос Что нужно выучить чтобы писать 3d игры?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [сайт][1]


  [1]: http://shatalov.su/index.php

Comment: а базовая алгоритмизация не нужна ?

Answer (score 5):

Дополню: нужно знать математику. Особенно геометрию, [проективные преобразования](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42086/Space-and-Matrix-Transformations-Building-a-3D-Eng), а также [приближённые вычисления](http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/8/). Посмотрите, сколько вопросов по этой тематике на [gamedev@SO](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) только на первой странице:

- [Shoot Projectile Towards Mouse Position](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50665)
- [Ways to “invert Z-axis” in shader-based core-profile OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50664)
- [Distance between two objects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50658)
- [OpenGL: why do I have to set a normal with glNormal?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50653)
- [Texturing 2D vectorial terrain (or simply masking texture)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50639)
- [How to build a math module and simulate a system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50597)
- [how to load normals for a model from texture2d?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50645)
- [Predicting ball direction on collision](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50538)

Насколько я понимаю, Java [не является](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/55104/6802) популярной платформой для 3D-игр, но вам придётся освоить *и* C, *и* C++.

Comment: Такая игрушка как *MineCraft* писана на **Java**. И она достаточно крутая)

Comment: от миникрафта меня укачивает и тошнит несколько часов если поиграю минут 40
не знаю почему, видимо потому что на java написана
отвратная игра

Comment: @IamS: это да, однако вы, думаю, не станете утверждать, что Java -- мэйнстрим в 3D-играх.

Comment: @VladD, нет, что Вы. Я просто считаю, что **Java** тоже не плохая. И не стоит об ней забывать.

Comment: @IamS: чем больше хороших языков (программирования) человек знает, тем лучше. Java -- хороший язык, его **надо** знать для того, чтобы лучше понимать программирование.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала определитесь вы хотите разрабатывать игру или движок. Если именно игру то лучше использовать готовые движки и библиотеки, следовательно зависит от движка но в основном такие языки как lua,c#. Но если решили писать собственный движок то тут c++/c, java, и другие. Но в этом случае разработка игры затянется на долго.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания игр нужны такие языки программирования как:

```
C#
C++ 
Java
```

> Я считаю, что это очень хорошие языки.

Когда занимался созданием игр, очень помог этот сайт [**клик**](http://gcup.ru/). Он посвящен для создания игр любой тематики. от **php** до **C++**

Желаю удачи :)

Comment: + сайт очень популярный, и Вам сразу ответят на любые вопросы. Да, и еще забыл упомянуть об **Unity 3D**.

Comment: с каких это пор Unity 3D это язык?

Comment: @Spectre, Парнон, мультиплатформенный инструмент. Опечатался, прошу прощения.